# Retrieving data from the table linking linking tables in PHPactiverecord

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I have three tables, and I am using members to find all the tasks they have completed.

```
class Task extends BaseModel {
static $has_many = array(
    array('members', 'through' => 'member_tasks'),
    array('member_tasks', 'class_name' => 'Member_task')
);

class Member extends BaseModel {
static $has_many = array(
    array('tasks', 'through' => 'member_tasks'),
    array('member_tasks', 'class_name' => 'Member_task')
);

class Member_task extends BaseModel {
static $belongs_to = array(
    'member', 'task'
);
```

if I call `$tasks = $member->myTasks()`

```
public function myTasks()
{
    return $this->tasks;
}
```

I can retrieve the items from the tasks table relating to that member. However, I have a `is_completed` flag that sits in Member_tasks table. How do I grab that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a member, the associations are accessible, so you can just get them trough `$member->tasks`, no need for the function.

The same goes for the table in between, so you'd have

```
foreach($member->member_tasks as member_task){
    //now you have a member_task object
    //use $member_task->is_completed  
}
```

You don't need to use the 'trough' definitions, especially if you want to look into the flags of the association. Just 'manually' going into the connecting table, looking at the entries and then getting the tasks would be the way.

If you want the task in that member_task, you probably need to define that association as well, as it doesn't look like you have that yet?